# How to set sth. on infinity in Java?

Tags: java

I want to implement the dijkstra algorithm and have to set each note at the beginning  to infinity.

I would like to know, if there is any function in Java which makes it easy.

Comment: First show us what you have implemented.

Comment: If you're talking about distance, simply take -1. A valid distance can't be <1 so you can easily identify -1 as "unseen".

Comment: Or use `null` and store all distance in `Long` objects

Comment: @rollback In dijkstra, we initialize the distance array with positive infinity.

Answer (score 1):

`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` if you are using `Double` to store your data.
Also note that this is not a number, which is nice depending on what you want to do. `Double` supports this concept.